# Jquery UI slide - element sliding in at wrong position then abruptly shifting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-animations

I'm trying to have a div slide in at the same time as another one slides out, but when sliding in the div is completely invisible at the target location until the slide animation is complete. I'm not sure why this is happening. Does it have something to do with the iframe that is in the location at the time of the slide?

Here is an example of the issue. jsfiddle.net/eqck8vn2/1/ when you click the Twitter tab on the left, instead of smoothly sliding in, it scrolls in at a position right below the currently visible element (the iframe) before just appearing at the final position (even though there is a sliding animation applied to it without any specified positioning).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's difficult to see, perhaps there is a z-index issue?

Comment: `twitterContainer` is positionned `absolute.` While the sliding animation (when supposed to see that `div`), something is setting the `top` position to a suspect value. [See printcreen](http://imgur.com/a/VNblA).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette *edit*: you're right. i made a jsfiddle and the top position seems to be at a weird area when you click the twitter button.. https://jsfiddle.net/eqck8vn2/1/ any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know if the *«weird area »* you noticed is same as I see... But this is only due to 2 animation at the same time. The element above not having dissapeared yet, it make the second one "jumpy". I [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/hkx9ogrd/) to place the second animation in the callback of the first one (in `twitterTransition()`). --- Would this be the issue on your site??? Try it ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes this is much better, thanks very much! the only problem is that because it's been placed in the callback, they don't occur at the same time and there is momentary blankness before the second slide on the website https://jsfiddle.net/hkx9ogrd/5/ <--- you can see what i mean using this updated fiddle (by clicking between the two tabs). anyway, that's a separate issue i think (though im not sure how to solve it), so if you post your answer i can mark it as solved. thanks again!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I fixed it by enclosing the elements in a container div and setting the position of the individual elements to absolute (so they are basically all at the same Y position, just all except 1 are hidden). that way the callback is not necessary and they both scroll starting from the same place. I really appreciate your help =]

Comment: Good! ;) In the mean time, I was playing with your code... Here is a new [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/7mLhre0n/)